Windows Backup: all options are greyed out. Is there still any way to configure Windows Backup backup to choose a backup location other than OneDrive?
Trying to make sense of the Windows backup native (pre-installed) app. When I run the app, its main window appears saying "Let's backup your PC to One Drive."
It has a number of boxes for various settings such as backup location (folders) and a separate "Settings" box.
However they all are greyed out and no down arrows appear on them, so  when I click on such a box, nothing happens.
Is there still any way to configure the backup? Such as an option to choose the backup location.

System: Windows 10 Home pre-installed on the laptop, Spanish version.
Laptop: HP Envy.

I  don't use OneDrive. I want to backup to a local  removable USB drive. But the damn thing seems to want to force me to use OneDrive.
